# Plotting already calculated Confusion Matrix using Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, confusion-matrix

How can I plot in Python a Confusion Matrix similar do the one shown [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_confusion_matrix.html) for already given values of the Confusion Matrix?

In the code they use the method `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix` which computes the Confusion Matrix based on the ground truth and the predictions.

But in my case, I already have calculated my Confusion Matrix. So for example, my Confusion Matrix is (values in percentages):

```
[[0.612, 0.388]
 [0.228, 0.772]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you check the [source](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b194674c4/sklearn/metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py#L119) for `sklearn.metrics.plot_confusion_matrix`, you can see how the data is processed to create the plot. Then you can reuse the constructor `ConfusionMatrixDisplay` and plot your own confusion matrix.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import ConfusionMatrixDisplay

cm = [0.612, 0.388, 0.228, 0.772] # your confusion matrix
ls = [0, 1] # your y labels
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=ls)
disp.plot(include_values=include_values, cmap=cmap, ax=ax, xticks_rotation=xticks_rotation)
plt.show()
```

Comment: When I ran this I got an error about shape not being defined. I rewrote the confusion matrix line as `cm = np.array([[tn,fp], [fn,tp]])` where I'm converting to a numpy array. I also took the liberty of creating variables that represent true and false positives and negatives.

Answer (score 8):

I saw that someone already answered this question, but I'm adding a new one that can be useful for the author or even for other users.

It is possible to **plot** in **Python** an already **Confusion Matrix** computed through `mlxtend` package:

> Mlxtend (machine learning extensions) is a Python library of useful
> tools for the day-to-day data science tasks.

**Snippet code:**

```
# Imports
from mlxtend.plotting import plot_confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Your Confusion Matrix
cm = np.array([[0.612, 0.388],
               [0.228, 0.772]])

# Classes
classes = ['class A', 'class B']

figure, ax = plot_confusion_matrix(conf_mat = cm,
                                   class_names = classes,
                                   show_absolute = False,
                                   show_normed = True,
                                   colorbar = True)

plt.show()
```

**The output will be:**

[image]

Comment: pssst `figure` should be `fig`

Answer (score 3):

I use a heatmap from seaborn. You can define a method:

```py
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns; sns.set_theme()
sns.set(font_scale=2)

def plot_matrix(cm, classes, title):
  ax = sns.heatmap(cm, cmap="Blues", annot=True, xticklabels=classes, yticklabels=classes, cbar=False)
  ax.set(title=title, xlabel="predicted label", ylabel="true label")
```

and use:

```py
cm = np.array([[0.612, 0.388], [0.228, 0.772]])
classes = ['class A', 'class B']
title = "title example"

plot_matrix(cm, classes, title)
```

the output is like this:
[image]